# Write a Pyspark query to calculate exploded_qty and imploded_qty when PACK_IND is Y or N

Tags: pyspark

Inventory_Table :

[image]

Item_Pack_Table

[image]

```sql
select a.CREATE_DT as create_date,a.TO_LOCATION_NO,A.ITEM_NO,SUM(a.ORDER_QTY) as IMPLODED_ALLOC_QTY, 
       SUM(a.ORDER_QTY * nvl(b.PACK_QTY,1)) as EXPLODED_ALLOC_QTY
from Inventory_Table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select ITEM_PACK_NO,sum(PACK_QTY) PACK_QTY from Item_Pack_Table
  group by 
    ITEM_PACK_NO)  b
ON a.ITEM_NO = b.ITEM_PACK_NO
GROUP BY a.CREATE_DT,a.TO_LOCATION_NO,A.ITEM_NO;
```

This above code works fine on calculating `IMPLODED_ALLOC_QTY` and `EXPLODED_ALLOC_QTY` when `PACK_IND` = **"Y"** , I want to include the calculation for when `PACK_IND` = **"N"** as `SUM(a.ORDER_QTY) as IMPLODED_ALLOC_QTY and SUM(a.ORDER_QTY) as EXPLODED_ALLOC_QTY`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If PACK_IND  can be added to group by then you can just use case/when to check which case you are handling, probably you can try with something like this:

```
select a.CREATE_DT as create_date,a.TO_LOCATION_NO,A.ITEM_NO,SUM(a.ORDER_QTY) as IMPLODED_ALLOC_QTY, 
     CASE b.PACK_IND WHEN b.PACK_IND = 'Y' THEN SUM(a.ORDER_QTY * nvl(b.PACK_QTY,1)) WHEN b.PACK_IND = 'N' THEN SUM(a.ORDER_QTY) END as EXPLODED_ALLOC_QTY
from Inventory_Table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  select ITEM_PACK_NO, PACK_IND, sum(PACK_QTY) as PACK_QTY from Item_Pack_Table
  group by
    PACK_IND, ITEM_PACK_NO  )  b
ON a.ITEM_NO = b.ITEM_PACK_NO
GROUP BY a.CREATE_DT,a.TO_LOCATION_NO,A.ITEM_NO,PACK_IND;
```